# Apache Spark search inside a dataset

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am new to spark and trying to achieve the following. I am not able to find the best way to do this. Please suggest.

I am using Spark 2.0 & its Dataset, Cassandra 3.7 and Cassandra Java connector

I have one ColumnFamily with partition key and 2 clustering keys. For example
myksyspace.myTable (some_id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, PRIMARY KEY (some_id, col1, col2))

I can get the data of myksyspace.myTable in a myTableDataset. The data has large number of rows (may be 200000).

After every 1 hour I get updated data from some other source where there could be some new data which is not in my database and I want to save it in database.

The data which I receive from some other source contains updated data but no value of “col2”. I get the rest of the data in a list, “dataListWithSomeNewData” in my Java code.

Now I want to match the data in list with data in myTableDataset and copy col2 from dataset to the list “dataListWithSomeNewData” and then generate new dataset and save it back in Database. This way my existing data will be updated. i want the new data to be inserted with new generated unique value for col2 for each list item. How do I achieve this?

I want to avoid collectAsList() on dataset to avoid out of memory as I may load large data in memory. With collectAsList(), the code works with small amount of data.

Any suggestion/idea on this. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why you need col2 as primary key ?  Remove it from primary key. and just insert all the updated data. Cassandra will upsert the updated data and insert the new data

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Only partition key and the col1 cannot make the primary key and cannot distinguish the data from other data. So col2 is required in primary key. So considering this is there a better and efficient way to solve this problem?